# Convert log timestamp into specific format from 2023-11-05T11:11:11.771+00:00 to 2023-11-05T11:11:11.771Z

Tags: java

- What I would like to achieve:

The input is some timestamp, in what I believe in the format logs would create. Something like `2023-11-05T11:11:11.771+00:00`

I want to convert this to this specific format: `2023-11-05T11:11:11.771Z` with Java

- What did I try:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "2023-11-06T10:28:45.774+00:00";
        long d = DateFormat.parse(s);
        System.out.println(d);
    }

}
```

- Question:

Unfortunately, this is not yielding the correct result.
How can I achieve this using Java 21, without having to bring external libraries if possible?

Comment: `System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse("2023-11-06T10:28:45.774+00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT));` -> `2023-11-06T10:28:45.774Z`

Comment: @MadProgrammer that looks like it one or two sentences to explain why. And then probably "be an answer" because that's just straight up an answer at that point =D

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I think there might be a better way to achieve it, as I'd be concerned about possible localisation issues, but that was just my "quick hack" attempt ;)

Comment: `s = s.replace("+00:00", "Z")` :)

Comment: I think this is a dup of many other questions; e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70384955,  The general answer (since Java 8) is use `java.time` classes, design or find the datetime patterns, and convert as per the first comment above.

Comment: I'd go with:
String input = "2023-11-05T11:11:11.771+05:00";
ZonedDateTime dateTimeValue = ZonedDateTime.parse(input, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
       String expectedResult = dateTimeValue.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT));

the answer linked above @StephenC is not perfect in my opinion because once you are creating your own patterns it's easy to loose accuracy due to Zone shift

Comment: Huh?  I am talking about these patterns - `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html`.  In this case you would use `X` to parse and `x` to format.  That is locale and local time zone independent.   (Now obviously, someone *could* create a pattern that is locale or timezone sensitive.  But we assume that programmers know not to do that.)

Comment: Also note that I said that this the **general** solution and I said "design **or find** the datetime patterns".  One of the ways to find existing patterns is to look in the javadocs for the classes where they would be defined.  Like `DateTimeFormatter` itself ... obviously.   (We shouldn't be training people to be google-and-cut-and-paste programmers.)